# react-native RECEIVE_SMS android permission always results 'never_ask_again'

Tags: android, react-native, android-permissions

I am requesting multiple permissions. All are working fine except **receive sms** where the result is always **'never_ask_again'**.

The following is the code I am trying:

```
_getPermissions = async () => {
try {
  const resuts = await PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple([
    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.RECEIVE_SMS,
    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_PHONE_STATE
  ]);
  if (
    resuts[PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION] !==
    PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED
  ) {
    alert("Permission not granted. The application may not work properly");
  }
  if (
    resuts[PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_PHONE_STATE] !==
    PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED
  ) {
    alert("Permission not granted. The application may not work properly");
  }
  if (
    resuts[PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.RECEIVE_SMS] !==
    PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED
  ) {
    alert("Permission not granted. The application may not work properly");
  }
} catch (err) {
  console.warn(err);
}
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Fix this line as opposite condition:

```
if (
  resuts[PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.RECEIVE_SMS] ===
  PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.DENIED
) {
  Alert.alert("Permission not granted. The application may not work properly");
}
```